# Отношение 1к1 и 1 ко многим в October CMS

Tags: laravel, october, octobercms

Имеется кастомный плагин в билдере, через который добавляются продукты на сайт. При добавлении продукта необходимо выбрать категорию.

Для выбора категории созданы две дополнительные таблицы: список категорий (id, bank_title, slug) и сводная таблица где хранится отношение продукта и категории (kredits_id, banks_id). Также создано поле 'tests' c типом 'relation'.

В модель продукта добавлено следующее:

```
public $belongsToMany = [

        'tests' => [
            'Bankeer\Kredity\Models\Banks',
            'table' => 'bankeer_kredity_kr_banks',
            'order' => 'bank_title'
        ]
    ];
```

tests – поле, где выбирается категория;
bankeer_kredity_kr_banks – сводная таблица;
bank_title – название категории в таблице категорий

В модели категорий обратное отношение:

```
 public $belongsToMany = [

        'kredits' => [
            'Bankeer\Kredity\Models\Kredits',
            'table' => 'bankeer_kredity_kr_banks'
        ]

    ];
```

Сейчас все работает, но для продукта можно выбрать несколько категорий а должна быть только одна. Как сделать, чтобы продукту выбиралась только одна категория, а в одной категории могло быть несколько продуктов?

Comment: Вам не нужна сводная таблица. В таблице `продукта` должен быть столбец `id категории`, таким образом вы получите обратную(`belongsTo`) связь один к одному, т.е у продукта может быть только одна категория. Соответственно, для получения всех продуктов в категории используете `hasMany`

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев Спасибо большое